# Creating new dataframes in loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have been working on a project, and I am stuck in a situation where I need to create multiple dataframes from a list of strings by filtering on values of the list of strings from another dataframe having a column containing the same values in the list. I am writing the code as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 5), 'B': np.random.randn(4), 'C':['A',A','B','C']}
list = df.C.unique()
list = list.tolist()
for r in list:
exec('df_{}=df[df.C=={}]'.format(r))
```

This has been throwing an error saying 'tuple index out of range'. Could anyone please quickly help on this?

Comment: My best guess is that you meant to write `.format(r, r)`, but that still throws an error. You'll have to go into more detail about the expected output of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object to `tuple`s and then to `dict`s:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('C')))
```

---

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('C')))
print (d['A'])
   A         B  C
0  1  0.670449  A
1  2 -1.265135  A

print (d['B'])
   A        B  C
2  3 -0.35891  B

print (d['C'])
   A         B  C
3  4  0.651704  C
```

Comment: @lit - answer was changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `dict` as it does the job safer than `exec`:

```
uniqueC = df.C.unique()

dfs = {'df_{}'.format(r): df[df.C==r] for r in uniqueC}
```

Now when you need a certain dataframe just call:

```
dfs['df_A']
#   A         B  C
#0  1  1.755507  A
#1  2 -0.371027  A
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary for a variable number of variables. You can use `groupby` in a dictionary comprehension:

```
dfs = {k: v for k, v in df.groupby('C')}

print(dfs['B'])

   A         B  C
2  3 -0.785257  B
```

I advise you do **not**:

1. Name variables after built-ins, e.g. do not use `list` as a variable name.
2. Use `exec` due to security shortcomings.
3. Forget to indent any `for` loops. Indentation is important in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! :)